# Getting The Latest Record Value Of Duplicated Record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

| Entry | Name | Color | Usage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Red | 0.5 |
| 2 | A | Red | 0.8 |
| 3 | A | Red | 1.5 |
| 4 | B | Blue | 1.3 |
| 5 | B | Blue | 0.8 |
| 6 | B | Blue | 0.6 |

So, I want to get the latest value of usage from the same record like

```
A, Red, 1.5  
B, Blue, 0.6
```

I've tried

```
SELECT MAX([Entry]) AS [Entry], [Name], [Color], [Usage]  
FROM [ColorUsage]  
GROUP BY [Name], [Color, [Usage]
```

The problem with that is, I got all the [Usage] value while I only wanted the latest value
If I don't group the [Usage] I can get it right but I need [Usage] value

Comment: so here's your query
`SELECT T.Name,T.Color,T.usage, R.Entry  
FROM (  
SELECT Name, color,MAX(Entry)AS Entry  
FROM Test GROUP BY Name, color   
) R  
INNER JOIN Test T  
ON T.Name = R.Name AND T.color=R.color  
AND T.Entry = R.Entry  `

Comment: @akshayphadke please don't provide answers as comments.